# compilation is turned off in jquery block

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc4. I am not able to understand why i am getting conditional compilation is turned off in razor view at jquery block.

```
var enableSteps=0;
$(document).ready(function () {
   var enableSteps = @ViewData["enableAllSteps"].ToString().ToLower();
});
```

I am getting at this line `var enableSteps = @ViewData["enableAllSteps"].ToString().ToLower();` in the above.

Comment: Is there an answer to this? It's not just throwing a warning, it's an error. It won't compile if the view is open is visual studio. This is a very simple but important feature. I've found solutions to this with mvc 3 involving turning on conditional compilation, however this didn't work with mvc 4

Answer (score 0):

That's a false positive.
The Visual Studio editor cannot handle Razor code nested in Javascript.
Your code will work fine.  (except that you probably meant to crate a Javascript string literal)

Comment: He's trying to output a javascript bool.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I can't even compile because of it, so the code does not run fine.

Comment: It compiles and works, it's just annoying to have an error instead of a warning. I get the "Conditional compilation is turned off" error in the error list within vs when the view file is open.

Comment: I was using RC version of Visual Studio 2012 and it wasn't compiling when the view was open. After applying the July update, I still got the same error, but it compiled at least.